# When a useCallback function is called both by a useEffect and an onClick handler is there a way to have exaustive deps to the useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint, lint

I have a pseudo-code React component similar to this one:

```
const codeApplier = ({ code, prices }: Props) => {
  const [isAccepted, setIsAccepted] = useState(false);

  const applyCode = useCallback(async () => {
    const validationResult = await callToApplyCode(code, prices);

    if (validationResult.status === "OK") {
      setIsAccepted(true);
    } else {
      setIsAccepted(false);
    }
    //do more stuff

  }, [code, prices]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAccepted) applyCode();
  }, [prices]);

  return <button onClick={applyCode} />;
};
```

The important parts:

- If the user clicks the button I want to apply the code
- If the prices change I want to reapply the code

Now, the component like this works fine, but the linter complains that on the useEffect I am not listing all the dependencies. The infamous exhaustive-deps rule.

The issue is: if I add "applyCode" (or even isAccepted) to the dependencies of the useEffect like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAccepted) applyCode();
  }, [isAccepted, applyCode, prices]);
```

then the linter is pleased, but useEffect is going to duplicate the call at each click.

1. change "code" -> automatically change "applycode" -> Expected
2. onclick -> call the new applycode -> Expected
3. callToApplyCode -> Expected
4. useEffect triggered by the "applycode" change -> applycode(); -> Unexpected
5. another callToApplyCode -> Not wanted

It this one of those cases where disabling exhaustive-deps is ok?
Or is there a way to refactor the component without angrying the linter?

I looked at this comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920#issuecomment-471070149
and various similar questions on StackOverflow, but I was not able to find an answer to my specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only the change of `prices` to trigger the `useEffect`, save the previous state of `prices` in a ref, and whenever the `useEffect` is triggered by deps change, check if current & previous prices are the same. If they are, bail out.

```
const codeApplier = ({ code, prices }: Props) => {
  const prevPricesRef = useRef(prices); // ref for previous state of prices
  const [isAccepted, setIsAccepted] = useState(false);

  const applyCode = useCallback(async() => {
    const validationResult = await callToApplyCode(code, prices);

    setIsAccepted(validationResult.status === "OK");

    //do more stuff

  }, [code, prices]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(prices === prevPricesRef.current) return; // bail out if current & prev prices are identical
    
    prevPricesRef.current = prices; // update prev prices
  
    if (isAccepted) applyCode();
  }, [prices, isAccepted, applyCode]);

  return <button onClick={applyCode} />;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

This code, thought, as you pointed out, would trigger the call at each change in "code".
The "code" comes from a controlled input, and we definitely do not want to call to apply the "code" at each keystroke!

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Cool! This does actually work! Thank you!